# Excel - Deleting zeros on the right side of the cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to delete the zeros on the right side of the cells if there are more then 3 zeros.
Example:

```
A                              B
12345                          12345
1230                           1230
12345600                       12345600
12000                          12000
12340000000000000              1234000
1234500000000000000000         12345000
```

Is it possible to excel using just formula in the cells of the column B??
How to do?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I assume these are text string values? Also, do you have all these values in `A1` concatenated through newlines? Or is this just a mishap in your question?

Comment: Sorry... It is column A and column B with several lines.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stretch (I'm prety sure it can be done better), but if you have access to `TEXTJOIN`, try the following in `B2`:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)="0000",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))))&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.)-3) != 0]"),A1)
```

Or:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A7,4)="0000",LEFT(A7,MAX((MID(A7,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A7))),1)<>"0")*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A7)))))+3),A7)
```

[image]

Note: It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

It looks frightening, agreed, but would yield the correct result as far as my testing went. For example `100000400000` would yield `1000004000`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers, given until now, are treating the numbers as strings, while I'd go for the numeric approach:

```
if mod(number,10000) = 0
then number = number div 1000;
return number;
```

Which means: if the number, divided by 10,000 equals 0 (if the number ends with '0000') then return the number, divided by a thousand (remove the last three zeroes).

You don't need this one time, but you need to remove all triplets of three zeroes, as much as possible, so instead of a simple if-loop, you might go for a while-loop:

```
while mod(number,10000) = 0
do number = number div 1000;
return number;
```

You can use this in a VBA function:

```
Public Function remove_ending_blanks(r As Range) As Double
  Dim temp As Double
  temp = r.Value
  While temp Mod 10000 = 0
    temp = temp / 1000
  Wend

  remove_ending_blanks = temp
End Function
```

You might also do this, using a formula, but the while-loop will need to be done using a circular reference, which is quite tricky.

Comment: The formulas I posted will work if text or numeric. It's probably not a great idea to use a UDF with a loop when you can use a native formula instead. The speed/efficiency will be drastically worse. Also, if you really wanted a UDF, just use a version of the formulas I posted.

Comment: Aaaand nevermind. Just re-read the question and found I read it wrong. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this shorter formula solution and worked in left max. 3 zeros on the right side.

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=0+TRIM(LEFT(A1,MATCH(9^9,INDEX(1/MID(A1,ROW($1:$99),1),0))+3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use this formula

```
 =IF(RIGHT(A1,4)="0000",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1/10^LEN(A1))-FIND(".",A1/10^LEN(A1))+3),A1)
```

Comment: What about `1020000`? Not my downvote..but you should rethink your solution =)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: These will give incorrect results. I mis-read the question and didn't realize you wanted to leave a max of 3 trailing zeroes. The below will remove all trailing zeroes.

If it's an unknown number of trailing zeroes, it gets tricky. You'd have to use something like this...

```
=(10^(LEN(RIGHT(VALUE(CONCATENATE("0.", A2)),LEN(VALUE(CONCATENATE("0.", A2)))-FIND(".",VALUE(CONCATENATE("0.", A2)))))))*VALUE(CONCATENATE("0.", A2))
```

If you know the number of trailing zeroes it becomes much easier, and can be done like this:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-3)
```

Where 3 in the above formula represents the number of trailing zeroes to remove. Another variation could be:

```
=A2/(10^3)
```

These formulas will work if text or numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Public Function ZeroTrimmer(r As Range) As String
    s = r.Text
    While Right(s, 4) = "0000"
        s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Wend
    ZeroTrimmer = s
End Function
```

[image]